# add Class for all options within "some selects with same parent class" using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, chained, chained-select

i want to use [jQuery Chained](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) in Wordpress Gravity Form.
for using jquery chained, i have to manually add classes in option elements within select lists with class "city". i have 2 selects with city class and 2selects with state class.

So i need 4 same selects exactly like this:

```
//////////////////// Home Place Address ////////////////////

<li class="state">
<select name="state">
  <option value="">Choose your State</option>
  <option value="tehran">Tehran</option>
  <option value="semnan">Semnan</option>
  <option value="qom">Qom</option>
</select>
</li>
<li class="city">
<select name="city">
  <option value="">Choose your City</option>
  <option value="city1" class="tehran">city 1</option>
  <option value="city2" class="tehran">city 2</option>
  <option value="city3" class="tehran">city 3</option>
  <option value="city4" class="semnan">city 4</option>
  <option value="city5" class="semnan">city 5</option>
  <option value="city6" class="qom">city 6</option>
  <option value="city7" class="qom">city 7</option>
</select>
</li>

//////////////////// Work Place Address ////////////////////

<li class="state">
<select name="state">
  <option value="">Choose your State</option>
  <option value="tehran">Tehran</option>
  <option value="semnan">Semnan</option>
  <option value="qom">Qom</option>
</select>
</li>
<li class="city">
<select name="city">
  <option value="">Choose your City</option>
  <option value="city1" class="tehran">city 1</option>
  <option value="city2" class="tehran">city 2</option>
  <option value="city3" class="tehran">city 3</option>
  <option value="city4" class="semnan">city 4</option>
  <option value="city5" class="semnan">city 5</option>
  <option value="city6" class="qom">city 6</option>
  <option value="city7" class="qom">city 7</option>
</select>
</li>
```

for adding classes to options, i am using this jquery code:

```
jQuery( "li.city select > option" ).slice(1,3).addClass( "tehran" );
jQuery( "li.city select > option" ).slice(3,5).addClass( "semnan" );
jQuery( "li.city select > option" ).slice(5,7).addClass( "qom" );
```

it works fine but just in Home Place Address section. so it won't add classes to fourth select in above code inside Work Place Address section.
i findout that i should use jquery .each(). but i can't get it working.
i tried this with no success:

```
jQuery("li.city select > option").each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.slice(1,3).addClass( "tehran" );
    $this.slice(3,5).addClass( "semnan" );
    $this.slice(5,7).addClass( "qom" );
});
```

Comment: in the second couple of select you dont ve a li element so the selector cant find nothing

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
var city = ["tehran","tehran","tehran","semnan","semnan","qom","qom"];
$("li.city select > option").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(city[index]);
});
```

Comment: tnx Aramil. using this mthod i have to put ~1300 names in city variable :D

Comment: Well, I was working with the info I had. You should've clarified that the amount of cities were much higher than on the example.

Answer (score 0):

ok  i figured it out:

```
jQuery('li.city select').each(function(){           
jQuery(this).find('option').slice(1,3).addClass( "tehran" );
jQuery(this).find('option').slice(3,5).addClass( "semnan" );
jQuery(this).find('option').slice(5,7).addClass( "qom" );
   });
```

working now. thank you